# Windows 7 Home can see but not access Win 7 Pro shares

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

Trying to connect a Win 7 Home machine to shares on a Win 7 Pro machine. On Win 7 Home, I can navigate Explorer to the machine, where the shares are listed. But when I try to navigate into the folder, I get "You do not have permission to access \Servername\Sharename". There's no prompt for username/password, and in any case, none should be needed with the permissions settings.

So, what can be blocking access?

More details:

On this network, I have machines A, B and C, where A and B are Win 7 Pro, and machine C is the problem machine, running Win 7 Home.

All three machines have drives set up as shares, (using "Advanced Sharing"), with permissions set to Everyone/Full access.

Now, all machines can see and access each other's shares, EXCEPT that machine C can see, but NOT access shares on machine A.

However, there is a slight wrinkle. Machine A has ten shares, which are eight drives, and two subsidiary folders (one is Users). Machine C cannot access any of these shares EXCEPT for:

-- one drive which happens to be an external USB drive, and also

-- the Users public share (but not the other subsidiary folder share).

Meanwhile

-- Machine B (W7Pro) has no difficulty accessing all the shares on A (W7Pro).

-- Machine C (W7Home) has no difficulty accessing shares on Machine B (W7Pro).

So it's something peculiar with Machine C accessing Machine A.

There is no Homegroup setup. All machines are set to same Workgroup. All are on the same LAN.

This symptom has arisen upon newly setting up Machine C (wiping and reinstalling Win 7 Home following virus). I don't know if this would have been a problem previously.

Ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: When you try to access a share, windows tries to send same credentials as you're logged in with to the server where a share resides. Maybe your usernames match? And AFAIK a user from different domain (every machine has a different domain in non-domain environment) is not included in Everyone group.

Comment: @Alex -- thanks for those comments. Indeed, I do have the logged-in username/pwd on machines A and B set the same, while C is different. However, that doesn't explain why A and B can access a share on C, and C can access a share on B, but not A.  Nor for that matter why C doesn't simply put up a "enter username/pwd" dialog when initial attempt to access A fails.